# Apple MATCH-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

i need some help with IOS Development, I am making an app that compares the pictures we take with the some pictures we have for comparison inside our files. However xcode is giving me an APPLE Match-O Linker error

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
   "_jpeg_free_small", referenced from:
      _free_pool in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _self_destruct in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
     "_jpeg_mem_available", referenced from:
      _realize_virt_arrays in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
    "_jpeg_free_large", referenced from:
         _free_pool in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
     "_jpeg_open_backing_store", referenced from:
       _realize_virt_arrays in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
     "_jpeg_get_large", referenced from:
      _alloc_large in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _alloc_barray in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      "_jpeg_mem_term", referenced from:
      _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _self_destruct in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_mem_init", referenced from:
      _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_get_small", referenced from:
      _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _alloc_small in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


(null): "_jpeg_free_small", referenced from:

(null): _free_pool in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): _self_destruct in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): "_jpeg_mem_available", referenced from:

(null): _realize_virt_arrays in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): "_jpeg_free_large", referenced from:

(null): _free_pool in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): "_jpeg_open_backing_store", referenced from:

(null): _realize_virt_arrays in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): "_jpeg_get_large", referenced from:

(null): _alloc_large in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): _alloc_barray in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): "_jpeg_mem_term", referenced from:

(null): _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): _self_destruct in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): "_jpeg_mem_init", referenced from:

(null): _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): "_jpeg_get_small", referenced from:

(null): _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): _alloc_small in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)

(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld /Users/cristhiansoria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeliEyes-cykfjtuipjnvchakwiafcdadoofn/Build/Intermediates/DeliEyes.build/Debug-iphoneos/DeliEyes.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DeliEyes normal armv7
    cd "/Users/cristhiansoria/Downloads/DeliEyes-master 2"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/cristhiansoria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeliEyes-cykfjtuipjnvchakwiafcdadoofn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/cristhiansoria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeliEyes-cykfjtuipjnvchakwiafcdadoofn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/cristhiansoria/Downloads/DeliEyes-master\ 2/DeliEyes/Framework -filelist /Users/cristhiansoria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeliEyes-cykfjtuipjnvchakwiafcdadoofn/Build/Intermediates/DeliEyes.build/Debug-iphoneos/DeliEyes.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DeliEyes.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -framework Slt -framework opencv2 -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenEars -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/cristhiansoria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeliEyes-cykfjtuipjnvchakwiafcdadoofn/Build/Intermediates/DeliEyes.build/Debug-iphoneos/DeliEyes.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DeliEyes_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/cristhiansoria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeliEyes-cykfjtuipjnvchakwiafcdadoofn/Build/Intermediates/DeliEyes.build/Debug-iphoneos/DeliEyes.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DeliEyes

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_jpeg_free_small", referenced from:
      _free_pool in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _self_destruct in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_mem_available", referenced from:
      _realize_virt_arrays in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_free_large", referenced from:
      _free_pool in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_open_backing_store", referenced from:
      _realize_virt_arrays in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_get_large", referenced from:
      _alloc_large in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _realize_virt_arrays in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_mem_term", referenced from:
      _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _self_destruct in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_mem_init", referenced from:
      _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
  "_jpeg_get_small", referenced from:
      _jinit_memory_mgr in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
      _alloc_small in opencv2(jmemmgr.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And we are just using opencv, basically there is a bad link with our picture.

Comment: You seem to be missing libjpeg.

Comment: any update still get error

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with OpenCV 3.0 RC1. Works well with version 2.4.10.